# how to read different files in differents runnable threads Java

Tags: java, multithreading, file, runnable

I need to read all `.txt` files in a folder with 4 Threads running at the same time. What can I do so each thread reads a different file. Ex: Thread 1 reads file 1, Thread 2 reads file 2... and so on until there's no more files to read.

```
Thread h;


public Hilo(){
    h= new Thread(this,"Hilo 1");
    h.start();
}

public void run(){
    int contador;
    File folder = new File("C:/Users/Jose/Desktop/java");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    for (File file : listOfFiles) { 
        if (file.isFile()) {
            contador=0;
            int i=0;
            //System.out.println(file.getName());
            Scanner scan = null;
            try {
                scan = new Scanner (file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (scan.hasNext()){
                String linea=scan.next();
                String[] lineas = linea.split("(?=[,.])|\\s+");
                if (Palindrome.is(lineas[i])){
                    contador++;
                }
            }
            scan.close();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `Executors` creates a thead pool ,you can use the pool

Comment: can you be more specific plz, im no veteran in java?

Comment: @passion there is the code

Answer (score 0):

```
package z;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

    File folder = new File("C:/Users/Jose/Desktop/java");

    File[] files = folder.listFiles();

    for(File file : files){

        exec.execute(new Worker(file));
    }

    }
}

class Worker implements Runnable {

    private File file;

    public Worker(File file) {
    this.file = file;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    int contador;
    if (file.isFile()) {
        contador = 0;
        int i = 0;
        Scanner scan = null;
        try {
        scan = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
        String linea = scan.next();
        String[] lineas = linea.split("(?=[,.])|\\s+");
        if (Palindrome.is(lineas[i])) {
            contador++;
        }
        }
        scan.close();

    }

    }

}
```

Comment: @JoseAlbertoSantiagoLuna  I print `lineas ` , it is OK .

Answer (score 0):

This is the code, without the palindromo method, its not necesary.

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Hilo numero1 = new Hilo();
        Hilo numero2 = new Hilo();
        Hilo numero3 = new Hilo();
        Hilo numero4 = new Hilo();
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hilo implements Runnable {

    Thread h;

    public Hilo() {
        h = new Thread(this, "Hilo 1");
        h.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        int c = 0;
        int contador;
        File folder = new File("C:/Users/Jose/Desktop/java");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        for (File file : listOfFiles) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                contador = 0;
                int i = 0;
                //System.out.println(file.getName());
                Scanner scan = null;
                try {
                    scan = new Scanner(file);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                while (scan.hasNext()) {
                    String linea = scan.next();
                    String[] lineas = linea.split("(?=[,.])|\\s+");
                    if (Palindromo.es(lineas[i])) {
                        contador++;
                    }
                    c++;
                }
                scan.close();
                System.out.println("La cantidad de Palindromos en el archivo " + file + " es de: " + contador);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, works... but the thing is that i need it to read different files each. your code prints exaclty what mine does, and i need it to be 4 Threads at the same time with different files. Thanks and sorry to bother.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:
1. Create a class ReadFiles:

```
public class ReadFiles {

    public interface IEvents {
        void onFile(File file);
    }
    int maxConcurrentThread = 5;
    ThreadPoolExecutor pool = null;

    volatile int countFiles = 0;
    String folder = "";
    IEvents event = null;

    public ReadFiles(String folder, int maxConcurrentThread) {
        this.folder = folder;
        this.maxConcurrentThread = maxConcurrentThread;
    }

    public void setEvent(IEvents event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    public void read() {

        ThreadPoolExecutor pool = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(this.maxConcurrentThread);

        File ffolder = new File(folder);
        File[] listOfFiles = ffolder.listFiles();
        for (final File file : listOfFiles) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                pool.execute(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        countFiles++;
                        event.onFile(file);
                    }

                });
            }
        }

        pool.shutdown();
    }

}
```

How to use:

```
int maxConcurrentThread = 5;
        ReadFiles read = new ReadFiles("C:/Users/Jose/Desktop/java", maxConcurrentThread);
        read.setEvent(new ReadFiles.IEvents() {

            @Override
            public void onFile(File file) {
                Scanner scan = null;
                try {
                    scan = new Scanner(file);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                while (scan.hasNext()) {
                    String linea = scan.next();
                    String[] lineas = linea.split("(?=[,.])|\\s+");
                    if (Palindrome.is(lineas[i])) {
                        contador++;
                    }
                }
                scan.close();
            }
        });
        read.read();
```

Comment: awesome answer, i think this works as adviced... but this is a homework and i wanted to understand, is it too much to ask if you could explain me or send me a link explaining your method? Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello Jose. The class ReadFiles use a ThreadPoolExecutor where you set the max thread at time. in this case you pass maxConcurrentThread=5. If your folder contain 1000 files not is good idea open 1000 thread at same time. you can set example 50 or 100 as maximimun. The ThreadPoolExecutor wait for free capacita and execute later the remaining thread for each files. The event onFile fire for each file and you can read all files.